# isdigit() Input testing for valid phone number

Tags: c

I'd like to create an algorithm that checks to see if the user has inputted a valid phone number (digits only). The program should keep prompting the user to enter a phone number until it is strictly digits. I've come up with the following.

Program Restrictions: Must use malloc (realloc is okay), phoneNum must be a pointer not an array, do-while required.

```
    int main (void)
    {
    int i, flag;
    char* phoneNum;
    phoneNum = NULL;
    phoneNum = malloc(sizeof(char));
    do{
        printf("Phone Number: ");
        fgets(phoneNum, sizeof(phoneNum) * 10, stdin);
        phoneNum[strcspn(phoneNum, "\n")] = 0;
        flag = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNum); i++){
            if(isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 1);

    printf("Valid Number: %s", phoneNum);

    return 0;
    }
```

However, isdigit seems to not work and I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the current/expected output. No compiling issues.

The Current Output:

```
Phone Number: 12345678
Valid Number: 12345678

Phone Number: abcdefg
Valid Number: abcdefg

Phone Number: 1234abcd
Valid Number: 1234abcd
```

Expected Output:

```
Phone Number: 12345
Valid Number: 12345

Phone Number: abcdefg
Phone Number: hijklmn
Phone Number: 123456
Valid Number: 123456
```

Thanks to all the users who helped me come up with a solution below, if you are stumbling upon this question here is the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
    {
    int i, flag;
    char* phoneNum;

    phoneNum = malloc(11);
    if (phoneNum == NULL){
        printf("Not Enough Memory!\n");
    }
    do{
        printf("Phone Number: ");
        fgets(phoneNum, 11, stdin);
        printf("<You entered: %s>\n", phoneNum); //check to see if program received user input.
        phoneNum[strcspn(phoneNum, "\n")] = 0;
        flag = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNum); i++){
            if(isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 0);

    printf("Valid Number: %s", phoneNum);
    free(phoneNum);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget that `fgets` includes a trailing `newline` in the string, if it was present in the input. That is included in the return value from `strlen`.

Comment: @WeatherVane All of that correct advice, sir, is useless, unless proper memory is allocated. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I see your answer, but OP will need to know this too.

Comment: @WeatherVane absolutely, no doubts. :)

Comment: Thank you @WeatherVane, I've used `phoneNum[strcspn(phoneNum, "\n")] = 0;` to remove the newline.

Comment: So you must have left that out of the code, but `fgets(phoneNum, sizeof(phoneNum) * 10, stdin);` is incorrect, perhaps lucky though, since `sizeof(phoneNum)` is the size of a pointer, not the space you (thought you) allocated.

Comment: Yes you're right I've made the edit in my code and added that line for users stumbling upon this.  The users below mentioned to malloc and multiplying `sizeof(char) * 11` which is the space I want to allocate. @WeatherVane

Comment: Why is the buffer `malloc'd` in the first place? Why not something like `char buf[80]; ... fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)`.  Code could later `strdup(buf)` if needed to right-size a string for subsequent use.

Comment: The requirement is to use a pointer and not an array, even though we know the size. @chux

Comment: @shrimpay Initially posting requirements that limit the selection of answers is useful for gaining better applicable answers, else one assumes all of C is fair game.

Comment: @chux I'm very new here thanks for the advice I've edited my post.

Comment: Often it is useful to surround text with brackets to clearly identify unexpected white-space (spaces, new lines) when printing a string `printf("Valid Number: <%s>", phoneNum);`
`

Comment: Did you mean to include `\r` in `strcspn` in your solution, based on comments below?

Comment: I actually didn't use \r, I'm not sure what it does and it caused some of the issues I was experiencing. Not sure why. @WeatherVane

Comment: `\n` is newline, `\r` is (carriage) return. There are various schemes for line endings in text files: some use one, some the other, some both, and the file system may convert one to another when reading a file, which might have been created on a different system. Including both line endings in `strcspn` with `"\r\n"` is harmless, but covers every eventuality, since `strcspn` looks for any of a *set* of characters, not an exact match.

Comment: I see, I'm not entirely sure why it caused a problem for me though. Even when I add it now, it goes back to never ending the loop. However, the more unsafe `\n` alone seems to work for my desired case. @WeatherVane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other faults have been answered, but you also have the loop condition the wrong way, since you set

```
    flag = 0;
    // ...  
} while (flag == 1);
```

after a bad digit test. Please try

```
} while (flag == 0);
```

**Edit** following a comment from OP. This is my test version. There is one compiler warning about signed/unsigned testing, and I was lax about the way I allocated memory (and your use of `fgets` is also lax), but the purposes of the example shows what I did - it's mostly your exact code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
    {
    int i, flag;
    char* phoneNum;
    phoneNum = malloc(20);
    do{
        printf("Phone Number: ");
        fgets(phoneNum, 20, stdin);
        phoneNum[strcspn(phoneNum, "\n")] = 0;
        flag = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNum); i++){
            if(isdigit(phoneNum[i]) == 0){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 0);

    printf("Phone Number: %s", phoneNum);
    return 0;
    }
```

Program session:

```
F:\Work\CTEST>test
Phone Number: 12345678
Phone Number: 12345678
F:\Work\CTEST>
```

Comment: The loop now never exits, even if a valid phone # is entered.

Comment: It does in my test version (with the corrected memory allocation and removal of newline).

Comment: Interesting, I literally copy and pasted your code. The program never exits the loop it continuously keeps asking for `Phone Number: ` even when I input an all digit number.

Comment: Mine *looks* as if it is asking for another phone number, because the answer is identical to the input, but it does return to the command prompt (run from console). Otherwise I can only think that you could try `phoneNum[strcspn(phoneNum, "\r\n")] = 0;` as I usually do, just precautionary.

Comment: I've edited the code, replace the last printf with `Valid Number: %s`, it still isn't working right? Or am I going crazy. I'm even using all the same libraries. EDIT: Oh, interesting I'm not sure what's going wrong then.

Comment: You mean it never prints `Valid Number nnnn`?

Comment: I've added some error checking print statements. Output: `Phone Number: 905510 You entered: 905510 Phone Number:` <-- still asking for more input.

Comment: Last resort is to delete the object and executable files and recompile.

Comment: I suspect OP is failing due to a `'\r'`, your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863991/isdigit-input-testing-for-valid-phone-number/42864015?noredirect=1#comment72835599_42864333) is good practice.

Comment: Oddly enough, that seemed to do it. Thanks so much for the help! Is it common practice on this site to edit my original question with the proper solution or just leave it, or provide the correct solution at the bottom?

Comment: No, please do not change the question (perhaps add the solution at the bottom), and people sometimes create an answer to their own question.

Answer (score 3):

The first and foremost problem is, you allocate memory using

```
 phoneNum = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and then, *without even checking for success of the allocation*, while taking input, you use

```
 fgets(phoneNum, sizeof(phoneNum) * 10, stdin);
```

which is clearly memory overrun. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to supply the exact size of the required memory to be allocated via `malloc()`, if you don't want to `realloc()` later.

Also, keep in mind, while scanning input using `fgets()`, you need to process the trailing newline yourself.

---

That said, as per your requirement, your logic seems wrong. Once the user enters all-digit number (which is correct), you should stop the loop, otherwise, keep looping. So, you need to change your logic to

- Initialize the flag to `0`
- In case the non-digit is found, set the flag to `1`. (you are doing already)
- Loop based on `flag == 1` (also you are doing already)

<kbd>**[See a modified version online](http://ideone.com/XFT5qZ)**</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't my malloc just create 1 byte, then in my fgets I'm multiplying that by 10, thus creating 10 bytes? (That's from my understanding, I'm clearly wrong). Also my local variable is initialized to flag = 1 in my do loop, which the program always enters. Should I initialize it outside the do loop aswell?

Comment: @shrimpay 1) no, just multiplying the size does not re-adjust the memory, you need to allocate memory by providing the size, or you need to reallocate it. 2) ignore the uninitialized part, misread the code.

Comment: you don't need to set flag outside as the do loop will always run once regardless of the test condition

Comment: 2) Ah I see thanks, however when I provide the size in my malloc statement by multiplying `sizeof(char) * 10` I still get undefined behavior in my program.

Comment: @shrimpay How so?

Comment: @ChrisTurner the flag needs to be set, it informs whether an all-digit phone number was entered.

Comment: Current Output with Edits: `Phone Number: abcdefg Valid Number: abcdefg`

Comment: @ChrisTurner and then, you'll hit UB by using an indeterminate value.

Comment: @WeatherVane the flag is set in the loop which it enters.

Comment: @WeatherVane it should reprompt the user for a `Phone Number:` until it is all digits. The output I just showed isn't the one I'm expecting.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't say the flag didn't need to be set at all - I was answering the question about initialising it outside the loop.

Comment: @shrimpay Just added a bit about the logic, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh from what I understood from the replies, I've removed the trailing newline, malloc'd 11 bytes for my string to store, and changed the logic however now the loop never exits and it always asks for `Phone Number:`

Comment: This answers would benefit with a correct use of `malloc() ... fgets()`

Comment: @chux Sorry, I did not get. Which part would be better with some elaboration? Let me know, I'll add clarity, thanks.

Comment: There are 2 lines of code showing what is wrong and a discussion about how to correct it, but no _good code_ example posted in the answer.  Maybe something like `#define PHONE_NUMBER_MAX_LENGTH  11   char *buf = malloc(PHONE_NUMBER_MAX_LENGTH + 2); ... fgets(buf, PHONE_NUMBER_MAX_LENGTH + 2, stdin)...` or your take using good programming practices.

Comment: @chux Sure, let me polish it a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

The statement:

```
phoneNum = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Creates space for only one character:

```
|1|
```

You are attempting to write a string with 11 characters: 1 + phone number...

```
|1|5|5|5|2|2|2|4|4|4|4|
```

...with space for the 1 digit.  But depending on how the phone number is entered, a phone number string might need the following:

- Space for 10 digits
- Space for preceding 1
- Space for newline character (if using `fgets()`, et. al. to read input)
- Space for NULL character.
- Space for phone number appropriate *punctuation*.

For example, your string could look like this:

```
|1|5|5|5|2|2|2|4|4|4|4|\n|\n|\0|
```

Or this:

```
|1|(|5|5|5|)|6|6|6|-|1|2|3|4|\n|\0|
```

Or this:

```
|1|.|5|5|5|.|6|6|6|.|1|2|3|4|\n|\0|
```

Even if handling phone number appropriate *punctuation* ( `(,),-,.` ) is out of scope, it would not be wrong to allocate extra memory for a reasonably sized string, such as 80 or more to be safe.  As long as you free it when finished, there is no harm in creating a little more space.

Change your memory allocation to:

```
phoneNum = malloc(80);//11 digit phone number, plus \n plus NULL Plus user unpredictability.
```

Comment: What's the difference between `malloc(11)` and `(sizeof(char) * 11)`?

Comment: because sizeof(char) == 1, ...  1 * 11 == 11.  There is no difference.  Its a simplification.  For other types, i.e. `int`, or `float`, sizeof(type) becomes more important.

Comment: @chux - agreed.  good points.  I addressed both in answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, for this assignment we only need to worry for this format `1234567` but for the next I will be back on this thread because we need the format `(xxx)xxx-xxxxx` Thanks for all the help with memory, still trying to debug some issues but for everyone reading this I appreciate it.

Comment: @shrimpay - you are welcome.  There are several very good suggestions in _all_ of the answers, be sure to up-click any that have been helpful, and if one answered your questions particularly well, click the accept check mark.